# Tangent of a unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know that tangent vector on unit circle in point $( a,b) $ is $ <b, a> $ in case of counter clockwise motion.
However, I don't get it.
If using tangent vector formula for a function of two variables,
shouldn't the tangent vector be:

from $x^2 + y^2 = 1, f_x = 2a $ and $f_y= 2b.$
So, the formula for tangent vector becomes $ <2a , 2b> $?

What am I missing here? How could I get the tangent vector using partial derivatives?

Comment: The gradient gives you a _normal_ to the curve, not a tangent. You’ve also got a sign error in your tangent vector.

Answer (score 2):

$r(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ is the unit circle parametrised so that it traverses the circle counter-clockwise.

$r'(t)=(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$ is the tangent at the point $r(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$.

In your notation, if $(a,b)$ is on the unit circle then $(-b,a)$ is the tangent vector at $(a,b)$.